# Maven project with JavaFX (with jar file in `lib`)

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I'm setting up a maven project, that is going to use JavaFX. Since I've heard JavaFX does not come with all versions of Java, I downloaded and put the `jfxrt.jar` file in a `lib` directory in my project.

1) How do I specify that the dependency (ie., JavaFX) should not be downloaded, but which is located in `lib`?

2) Does this then mean the project can be built on any machine with JDK (and not necessary JDK 1.7 - update 9+) ?

Comment: I have the same issue, the problem was corrupted `jfxrt.jar`, I would suggest to reinstall Java or for quick fix replace `jfxrt.jar` with the one where this JavaFX application is running fine.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**2019 Update for Recent JavaFX Versions**

As of Java 11, JavaFX has been decoupled from the JDK, so JavaFX libraries are no longer automatically bundled together with a JDK install (as they were for instance in the Oracle JDK 8 distribution).  Instead, the JavaFX system is now designed as a set of separate libraries independent from the JDK, which can be downloaded from a repository by a tool such as Maven for use by your application.

openjfx.io have a very short tutorial on using JavaFX 11+ with Maven:

- https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven

This tutorial recommends use of the [OpenJFX JavaFX Maven Plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) and provides the following sample maven pom.xml project file for a "hello, world" style application.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>12.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>HelloFX</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Note that the [org.openjfx JavaFX maven plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) used for Java 11+ is different from the [com.zenjava JavaFX maven plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) used for Java 8 and 9, so use the appropriate one for your Java version.

**Suggested Approach**

For building JavaFX apps with Maven:

1. Use the [com.zenjava maven JavaFX plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin) with Java 8 and 9 AND/OR
2. Use Java 8 or 9 and don't specify any kind of Maven dependency for JavaFX OR
3. Use the [org.openjfx maven JavaFX plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) with Java 11+.

Unlike Java 7, with Java 8 it is unnecessary to set JavaFX as a maven dependency, because JavaFX is on the standard Java runtime classpath (similar to the way Swing is today).

**Opinion**

I think the approach in your question of placing the `jfxrt.jar` file in a project `lib` directory is flawed.

The reasons it is flawed are:

1. JavaFX also includes native libraries, so you would need to include them as well (in a location where `jfxrt.jar` would be able to find them).
2. A given version of JavaFX will only be certified to operate against the version of the JDK it is shipped with, so the JavaFX runtime you place in your project's `lib` directory may not work against a later JDK version, such as JDK 8.
3. Future versions of the JDK such as JDK 8 will include JavaFX on the default classpath of the JDK, so you may get conflicts with the version you place in your `lib` directory.

In summary, JavaFX should be treated as part of the Java runtime system, not as a project library.

**JavaFX System Dependency Sample**

If you must use Java 7 and you don't want to use the JavaFX maven plugin, then you can take the less recommended approach:

- Reference the JavaFX library from the jdk (not your project `lib` directory) as a [maven system dependency](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies).

This sample is provided for Java 7 only and is not required (and will not work as is) for Java 8.  Java 8, places the jfxrt.jar in ${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, which is on the default Java runtime classpath, making a system dependency for Java 8 irrelevant.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javafx</groupId>
  <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
  <version>${java.version}</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

If you package your application using a system dependency like this, then you need will need to write some execution instructions for your users so that they can add jfxrt.jar to the runtime classpath when running your application on Java 7.  This is a very good reason not to use this approach.

If you choose to use the maven system dependency approach, you may also wish to use the maven [antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to embed calls to the [JavaFX ant tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm#CIADCBJG) as in [this sample](http://code.google.com/p/willow-browser/source/browse/pom.xml).  You may also want to use the [maven enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) to ensure that your application is built against at least the minimum required version of Java containing a JavaFX version required by your application to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to use the approach that you mentioned (ie., specify the local path to the `jdk1.7.0_09` dir, but I couldn't install any higher version of the jdk other than `jdk.1.7.0_u4` on my Snow Leopard. (I've tried the oracle website, but the installers would only work on Mountain Lion!) Do you happen to know how to get the `1.7.0_09` version to install on Snow Leopard? (Because that's the lowest version of Java that supports JavaFX, isn't it?)

Comment: JavaFX 2 doesn't work with Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6) - the minimum required OS X version is 10.7 (lion).

Comment: So I can't develop on an OSX 10.6, but if I built the executable jar, could I execute it on OSX 10.6?

Comment: No, my understanding is that JavaFX 2 makes use of native OS X system calls which are not present on OS X 10.6, so the resultant jar would not work (even a [native packaged app](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm) would not work either). For further info see (my answer to): [Javafx 2.2 and Snow Leopard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370529/javafx-2-2-and-snow-leopard])

Comment: Avoid the path/platform/version dependency of a hardcoded lib directory with: `<systemPath>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>` no additional properties needed.

Comment: The javafx.runtime.lib.jar property allows you to use JavaFX 2.2 as a separate install with jdk6 or to specify a javafx lib from a java version different from that used to run maven.  But you probably don't need those features, so using earcam's suggestion of the default java.home property is a very good one.  I'd still advise using zonski's JavaFX maven plugin instead though.

Comment: Java 8 changed the location to lib/ext `<systemPath>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>`

Comment: This answer assumes you're using Oracle's shipping of a Java 8 JDK. The OpenJDK distribution doesn't seem to include javafx.

Comment: If you do not wish to use Oracle's JDK distribution, there is an [JavaFX distribution for Ubuntu based upon the the OpenJDK sources](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjfx), or you can build [JavaFX for OpenJDK from source](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main).

Comment: Things got a little more complicated recently e.g. on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. You need to specifically install a fitting JavaFX now - the default might not give you the desired mileage. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166267/how-do-i-get-java-fx-running-with-openjdk-8-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts/56166582#56166582