# JavaFX Projects gone?

Tags: javafx

I have been trying to find a place to download the plugin, allowing the creation of JavaFX projects, but without success.
I have installed the newest Java SDK8u65-windows-x64 but it doesn't support JavaFX Projects, or at least I couldn't figure how to create one!

Does anyone know if they have temporally taken the url's where we used to be able to download JavaFX plugins from, or is it only me, who can't find them on the Oracle website?

Thank you !

**EDIT:** The problem was, that I was using Eclipse Mars, which for some reason doesn't allow to auto import JavaFx, as it has some odd access restrictions on the JRE system library. How I solved it was I installed the e(fx)clipse plugin and I was able to import javafx components successfully after that!

Comment: Which plugin are you talking here? JavaFX used to have a SDK for Java 6 and Java 7, but its now a part of JDK 8. If you have JDK8+ installed, you can create JavaFX projects, without having anything else to install.

Comment: I said plugin, as that's how I remember I used to have it  back in the days. Now I need to use it again, so when I upgraded to JDK 8 and read that FX is supposed to be installed along with JDK8, I couldn't find it under the 'Create new Project' options, so I wanted to ask you guys where I can actually find it?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: For eclipse, you can either create a Simple Java Project or install [efxclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) to have more support for JavaFX projects.

Comment: When you say 'a Simple Java Project' that doesn't involve the JavaFX libraries, does it? As I've tried importing some of them, but without any success!

Comment: Are you using Eclipse Mars?

Comment: Yes I am using Eclipse Mars.. Can that be the problem?...

Comment: Ahh, I see. You most probably would want to go through [Eclipse Mars won't auto import JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383248/eclipse-mars-wont-auto-import-javafx). Specially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33414711/1759128). This has to do with access restrictions on the JRE system library.

Comment: Oh my God! I spent so much time trying to find where the problem is! Okay I shall try another Eclipse version then! Thank you very much!

Comment: You can just install efxclipse plugin and things will be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop JavaFx straight away if you are using intellij Idea and perhaps some other ides

[image]

But if you are using eclipse, you should install the e(fx)clipse for your version.

Try this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html#for-the-lazy)

Also if you have more than one JDKs on your system, try to use jdk 8 an the default

Right click your project > properties

Then elect “Java Build Path” on left, then “JRE System Library”, click Edit…

Select "Workspace Default JRE"

Click "Installed JREs"

Check out the list and select jdk 8....

If you don't see it, click Search…, navigate to your jdk8 path, then click OK
Now you should see all installed JREs, select the one you want
Click OK

Comment: It is not true that you cannot develop JavaFX apps in Eclipse without the e(fx)clipse plugin. This plugin just provides some tools which make your life easier but technically it is not necessary.

Comment: May be you have not set up JDK 8 as the default project JDK if you installed more than one otherwise it should work

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses!

The problem was, that I was using Eclipse Mars, which for some reason doesn't allow to auto import JavaFx, as it has some odd access restrictions on the JRE  system library.

How I solved it was I installed the e(fx)clipse plugin and I was able to import javafx components successfully after that!

Comment: Great, that's what i was saying  "**But if you are using eclipse, you should install the e(fx)clipse for your version.**"