# How to allow auto import of JavaFX packages with an fxml file with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml

I would like to auto import the packages in Eclipse in an fxml file like :

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
```

When I press ctrl + shift + o or ctrl + space, nothing happens.
When I type them manually the code works well.

I also would like to have autocompletion while in the fxml file (I do have it while writing java code).

I have e(fx)clipse installed and I added the JARs files of JAVAFX sdk 11.0.2. I also have jre1.8.0_241 and jdk 13.0.2 and Eclipse 2019-12.

I already tried both first answers in this post : 
[Eclipse Mars won't auto import JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383248/eclipse-mars-wont-auto-import-javafx)

Note: I am a beginner.

Comment: I guess e(fx)clipse can't do that. Why don't you use SceneBuilder for managing FXML views? It is easier and cleaner than manual editing.

Comment: I didn't know about SceneBuilder. It's definitely easier. Thank you.

Comment: Intelij(also free and open source in the community edition) can do so