# Javafx cannot be resolved in Eclipse although working with JavaFX Library

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a project in **Eclipse** where I use the `JavaSE-14` Modulepath and `JavaSDK` Classpath. However, every time I try to import a class from `JavaFX` it says `the import javafx cannot be resolved`. Any help? I'm new to programming in Java so please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Change SDK to `JAVA 8`.

Comment: Please check if the following could solve the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592775/javafx-is-not-recognized-in-eclipse
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819052/how-do-i-import-javafx-into-eclipse

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me...

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX is now a separate bundle to JDK so if you wish to use JDK14 with Eclipse then download a compatible [JavaFX SDK](https://openjfx.io/). JavaFX 15.0.1 requires JDK 11 or later.

Then set up your project build path - right mouse on project: `Build Path > Configure Build Path`.

In Libraries tab it is easier to define a variable: Add Variable JAVAFXLIB and pick the lib dir of your JavaFX release - example: set JAVAFXLIB to `C:/java/javafx-sdk-15/lib`.

Then use the variable in the Module Path or Class Path of your project - example `JAVAFXLIB/javafx.base.jar`.

If you plan to release your application you may want to get hold of the `JavaFX jmods` release as well. Then you can use `jlink` to package Java runtime with your JavaFX dependencies as one unit - this will simplify your runtime-environment.