# Eclipse Neon Java proposals does not propose JavaFX classes

Tags: eclipse, javafx, java-8, eclipse-neon

I am using Eclipse Neon with jdk-1.8.0_74.

When typing

```
public class HelloWorld {
    Label
}
```

and hitting Ctrl-Space after Label eclipse used to propose javafx.scene.control.Label (as well as other classes).

It does no longer do so. The class itself is present however, because I can manually import it and when using the "Open Type" dialog (Ctrl+Shift+T) the class will be found.

Is this a bug in eclipse?

Comment: Could you try: In preferences: Java -> Editor -> Content Assist: Restore defaults ? And also check in Java -> Appearance -> Type Filters that it is not on the blocking list.

Comment: Although originally targets Java 7, I guess http://stackoverflow.com/q/15592775/114313 is highly related. More precisely, on Linux with OpenJDK JavaFX might not be installed by default; and I'd look at the classpath of the Java project.

Comment: @Zotan As the OP can manually import the class, the scenario which you refer to is not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. In the Preferences Dialog, under **Java > Appearance > Type Filters** one has to uncheck **Hide forbidden references**.

For whatever reason eclipse seems to think that references to public JavaFX-Classes are forbidden.