# JavaFX is not recognized in Eclipse Neon, JDK 8 after installing e(fx)lipse and manually adding JRE

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I am trying to go through this tutorial : http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1

For some reason, JavaFX is not recognized and I am not sure why.

I am running the eclipse version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
I am using Java JDK 1.8 runtime environment, (I also tried using JDK 1.7 runtime environment per the tutorial).
I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.
I installed e(fx)clipse.

I have manually added jfxswt.jar to my build path for the project, but my project still doesn't recognize the javafx import. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

[image: With JavaFX SDK library added to build path]

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK, or an Oracle JDK? If it's OpenJDK, it does not ship with JavaFX, which you will need to [get separately](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main) (or just switch to the [Oracle JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)).

Comment: jfxswt.jar is just extra stuff to interface to SWT. You need the jfxrt.jar for the main JavaFX which is not included in OpenJDK (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34243982/2670892))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX is not recognized in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592775/javafx-is-not-recognized-in-eclipse)