# JavaFX: Latest version of javafx-runtime

Tags: maven, javafx-2, dependency-management

What is the latest version of javafx runtime?

I tried to add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.25</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following error while saving my pom.xml.

`Missing artifact com.oracle:javafx-runtime:jar:2.2.25`

I tried updating the project dependencies but that did not help. Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Current Version of JavaFX - 10/3/2013*

The current version of JavaFX is JavaFX 2.2.40 and is distributed inside Oracle Java 7u40.

You can get the development kit for Java7u40 from:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

And if you just need the runtime and not the rest of the development kit, it is available at:

- [www.java.com/getjava/](http://www.java.com/getjava/)

*Regarding JavaFX and Maven*

I think you are trying to use JavaFX as a Maven dependency.  However, JavaFX is not hosted in a public Maven repository.  Similar to other parts of the Java runtime like the Java collections libraries or the Swing GUI toolkit, JavaFX does not need to be hosted in a Maven repository as it is included as part of the underlying Java runtime.

To see how to use JavaFX from Maven as system dependency, refer to the Stackoverflow question: [Maven project with JavaFX (with jar file in `lib`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278215/maven-project-with-javafx-with-jar-file-in-lib).

If you are working with JavaFX and Maven, likely the best solution is to use the [JavaFX Maven Plugin](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/).