# Cannot find jfxrt.jar (javafx) at runtime

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am currently using just one class from javafx.util package : `Pair`, because I did not want to implement my own Pair class, so I thought this would be a reasonnable solution.
However, I am working with Intellij, which seems to know where to find the jfxrt.jar, so I did not notice that this could cause problems.

In fact, when I run my main from Intellij, all is right, but when I try to package the application with Maven, and then `java -jar myapp.jar`, the application needs the Pair class, and apparently doesn't find it :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/util/Pair`

So I searched around, and here is what I can tell you :

- My JDK is `1.7.0_40`, so I know jfxrt.jar is bundled, and I found it.
- Maven version : `3.1.0`
- I am on windows seven
- I tried to add %JAVA_HOME%\lib\ to my PATH variable, did not change anything
- I tried to add this system dependency in my pom.xml :

  ```
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javafx</groupId>
          <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ```

But it does not seem to change anything, and even if it sound silly, I tried to copy/paste jfxrt.jar, in a lib folder within my jar, and surprisingly, it did not work either...

- I use the maven-assembly-plugin like this :

  ```
  <groupId>minmax</groupId>
  <artifactId>minmax</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javafx</groupId>
          <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <archive>
                      <manifest>
                          <mainClass>fr.tlasnier.jeux.puissance4.ihm.Puissance4Main</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                  </archive>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
              </configuration>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                      <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                      <goals>
                          <goal>single</goal>
                      </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
  ```

Should you have any suggestion, please go ahead (might be another solution for my Pair problem that does not rely on javafx ...)

Comment: Writing that class would have been quicker than writing this question and doing all the research. Why exactly don't you want to put [these few lines](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/util/Pair.java) somewhere in your code?

Comment: Because I wanted to do it in a "cleaner" way that copy/pasting code. Afterall, why is maven there if we cannot use dependencies? But thanks anyway, I will do that until I have another solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven project with JavaFX (with jar file in \`lib\`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278215/maven-project-with-javafx-with-jar-file-in-lib)

Comment: I would not even consider that a cleaner way if that's the only thing you use from a library. Reason somewhere along those lines: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_principles

Answer (score 0):

How are you packaging your application? You could try with maven-assembly-plugin for packaging, there is a descriptor called jar-with-dependencies which adds them to the final artifact, you then call mvn package.

Answer (score -1):

jfxrt.jar is not in lib folder ...

It is in lib/ext/

e.g., jdk1.8.0_211/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar