# Java fx error in Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I'm trying to run an application using JavaFX in mac os but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: getScaleFactor
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:281)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:124)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:163)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: getScaleFactor
at com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacApplication._initIDs(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacApplication.<clinit>(MacApplication.java:34)
at com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacPlatformFactory.createApplication(MacPlatformFactory.java:33)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.Run(Application.java:103)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:271)
... 5 more
```

I package the application in one jar using fat jar plugin for eclipse with and without jfxrt.jar, and the problem still exists

Comment: What Java Version do you run?

Comment: My first guess would have been an outdated java version but other than that from the stacktrace I can't think of the cause since JavaFX should be shipped with that version.

Answer (score 1):

> application in one jar using fat jar plugin

Don't do that.  If you want to use that plugin, to package JavaFX applications, then log a feature request with the plugin creators to add JavaFX support to the plugin.

Use packaging methods which are aware of JavaFX and will correctly package your JavaFX application, for example:

- [JavaFX Gradle Plugin](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle)
- [JavaFX Maven Plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin)
- [Oracle JavaFX deployment tools (currently JavaFX ant tasks or the javafxpackager)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm).

There is a chance that onejar might work for you out of the box with Java 8 as some of the classloading rules for JavaFX changed to be more relaxed for Java 8, I guess you could try it and see if it works.

> I package the application . . . with . . . jfxrt.jar

I don't recommend this unless you are packaging the entire JRE with the app.  Reasons for not doing this are explained in the answer to: [Maven project with JavaFX (with jar file in `lib`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278215/maven-project-with-javafx-with-jar-file-in-lib) (I know you are not using Maven, but the reasoning is similar).