# The import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode cannot be resolved

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, javafx, classpath

I've been trying to use import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode because I want to use SwingNode in my project, but the error "cannot be resolved" comes up.

I have a JavaFX SDK in libraries, so I don't know where the problem is.

Does anyone have any idea what it can be?

Comment: Get https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing library from maven

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [Oracle Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (it places JavaFX classes on the default classpath).
2. Don't manually place JavaFX libraries in your classpath.

See [Maven project with JavaFX (with jar file in `lib`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278215/maven-project-with-javafx-with-jar-file-in-lib) for more information (you probably aren't using maven but much of the background info and reasoning applies equally to your question).