# JavaFX build for Java6 on Mac

Tags: java, macos, javafx-2

Our application is Javafx based. Due to some reasons we have to port our application with java6 on Mac.

But according to the download section on [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxjdk6-1728173.html), there is no build available for JavaFx on Java6 on Mac.

Is there any Javafx build available which can be used with Java6 on Mac?

Comment: See: [JavaFX 2.2 and Snow Leopard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370529/javafx-2-2-and-snow-leopard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any Javafx build available which can be used with Java6 on Mac?

No JavaFX 2.x+ build is available for Java6 on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

This is problematic since JavaFX is bundled with JRE 7, but that is unavailable on Mac OS X 10.6

My suggestion would be to use the [Native Bundle](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_for_javafx) feature of JavaFX2.2, which lets you package an entire JRE with your application and provides a native executable to launch your app. You can automate the entire thing by using [E(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/), and its a matter of checking one checkbox. There are plenty of guides on the internet on how to do it with or without the e(fx)clipse plugin.

Comment: But how will native Bundle be helpful then?

Comment: I might have misunderstood you, please be aware that JavaFX for JRE6 is **only available for Windows**. Using Native Bundle, you can package your app with a JRE 7 and the target machine has no need to have a JRE installed at all. I sort of half-guessed that the reason you need to port to JRE 6 is that your target machine is on OS X 10.6, where JRE 7 is not availabe, and Native Bundle is the only way that I know to make this work. Apologies if that assumption was incorrect.